# Distinguish between Log a Call and normal Task

Tags: tasks, activities

I am trying to distinguish when we create a task using "Log a Call" vs when I create a normal task for suppose a Lead record.

Currently I am not able to find any way to distinguish between these two.

Is there a way to identify in a Task trigger when we create the same using "Log a Call" button?

Thanks,

Ray

Answer (score 0):

Logging a call reflects a task that already happened. They are not scheduled and no reminder will be created. Scheduling a call gets the reminder.